# Borderless Button on Pre-Lollipop with Support Library

Tags: android, android-layout, material-design, android-support-library, android-design-library

I am making borderless flat button using support library (23.0.1). It works normal on Lollipop. However on pre-Lollipop when I press button Its color changes to `colorButtonNormal` color like it's a normal button.

I don't think so it's a normal behaviour and focused color should be grey like on Lollipop.

Here's the screenshot from Lollipop and Pre-lollipop.

First normal behaviour on Lollipop:
Borderless button in normal state and focused state on Lollipop

[image]

Not normal behaviour on Pre-Lollipop (**Desire color is gray like above but it's not**):
Borderless button in normal state and focused state on Pre-lollipop
[image]

Theme

```
<style name="AppTheme.Base" parent="Theme.AppCompat.Light.NoActionBar">
//other stuff 
        <item name="colorButtonNormal">@color/orangeColor</item>
        <item name="buttonBarButtonStyle">@style/BorderlessButtonStyle</item>
</style>

<style name="BorderlessButtonStyle" parent="Widget.AppCompat.Button.Borderless">
        <item name="android:textColor">@color/blueTextColor</item>
</style>
```

And now button in layout:

```
<Button
            android:id="@+id/btnForgotPassword"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="@string/forgot_your_password"
            style="?attr/buttonBarButtonStyle"
            />
```

Any way to get it write using AppCompat Theme and styles without of making separate Drawables.

Comment: Just a thought but have you tried changing `<item name="colorButtonNormal">@color/orangeColor</item>` to `<item name="colorButtonNormal">@android:color/transparent</item>` in your res/styles.xml (You can keep it the way it is in the v-21/styles)?

Comment: @AdvaitS colorButtonNormal also changes the backgroundTint of normal button.

Answer (score 25, accepted):

Borderless Button works on both Post and Pre Lollipop version with Support Library but there's a small difference between their onPressed color.

Pre-Lollipop: By default onPressed color is same as default Button color set using `colorButtonNormal`.

Lollipop: By default onPressed color is light grey, which is ideal.

You can make a Borderless Button like this:

```
<Button  
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:text="Name"
    style="@style/Widget.AppCompat.Button.Borderless"/>
```

Now If you want to have the same onPressed color on all versions then you can set `colorControlHighlight` in a new theme and set that theme on Button.

```
<Button  
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="Name"
        android:theme="@style/BorderlessButton"
        style="@style/Widget.AppCompat.Button.Borderless"/>
```

And theme in your style:

```
<style name="BorderlessButton" parent="Theme.AppCompat.Light">
      <item name="colorControlHighlight">YOUR COLOR</item>
</style>
```

**Updated**: You can use `android:theme` attribute for a `View` since Android 5.0 Lollipop and AppCompat v22.1.0 (and higher).

Comment: How do you set "theme" for a single button? I thought Android allows to set themes only to viewgroups and activities.

Comment: @AlexPetrenko yes you can use `android:theme` on a View since Android 5 and AppCompat v22.1.0 (and higher) https://plus.google.com/u/0/+AndroidDevelopers/posts/JXHKyhsWHAH

Comment: That's a great link, I should've seen it earlier. Thanks!

Answer (score 3):

Adding `style="?borderlessButtonStyle"` to the `Button` worked fine for me.

Answer (score 0):

You are using the android implemented style of "buttonBarButtonStyle" since you are calling it via `?atr` - use `style="@style/BorderlessButtonStyle` instead.

Edit: Leave your xml as it is, but you can change it to your wanted behaviour like this:

```
AppCompatButton button = (AppCompatButton) findViewById(R.id.btnForgotPassword);

ColorStateList colorStateList = new ColorStateList(new int[][] {{0}}, new int[] {0xFF969696});  
    //969696 is your wanted grey color, just change it
button.setSupportBackgroundTintList(colorStateList);
```

Comment: android implemention is `?attr/android:buttonBarButtonStyle` - Without android it's support library implementation that should work on pre-lollipop - Also, in theme `buttonBarButtonStyle` override with own textColor which works. The thing doesn't work is on focus background color on pre-lollipop.

Comment: Ok sorry, my bad. But you can add your wanted behaviour programmatically, I'll update my answer.

Answer (score 0):

why do you worry with some things just go with this and be free

```
<Button
   android:id="@+id/btnForgotPassword"
   android:layout_width="wrap_content"
   android:layout_height="wrap_content"
   android:text="@string/forgot_your_password"
   android:background="@drawable/abc_btn_borderless_material"
/>
```

and now careless about api stuff